# pairwise distances with a metric pdist does not have

Tags: matlab

I'm having trouble trying to visualize writing code for my problem because I'm so used to using `pdist`.

What I would like to do is to compute all non-absolute distances of a vector. so that my metric is just (x-y), where x and y are two values in my vector.

Typically, I would just do the following:
`squareform(pdist(X(:,i))`

However this would return the EUCLIDEAN distance, not my distance.
Is there a way to do this with pdist? Or maybe is there a different method?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to compute.

For `X=[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]`

For the FIRST matrix, the matrix of all differences of the elements in the first column, we should have

`D=[(1-1), (1-4), (1-7); (4-1), (4-4), (4-7); (7-1), (7-4), (7-7)]`

or

`D=[0,-3,-6;3,0,-3;6,3,0]`

Comment: I just fixed the `distfun` to do what you need.  Sorry for the mistake earlier.  It needed `bsxfun` and `sum`.  Tested this time.

Comment: While it's useful to see that you can come up with your own metric, this isn't quite what I wanted..let me try to come up with an example. Thanks a ton for your help though.

Comment: Also, I apologize for the confusion, I was mixed up on what I really wanted I think.

Comment: No problem.  For you example matrix of `X=[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]` giving the matrix `D=[0,-3,-6;3,0,-3;6,3,0]`, I posted the loop to do that.  note that you can't do this with `pdist` since this is not symmetric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to use try "city block" metric of [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html):

```
pdist(X,'cityblock')
```

That's close but not quite what you need, so you can define your own distance function and use it as follows,

```
distfun = @(XI,XJ) sum(bsxfun(@minus,XI,XJ),2); % swap XI,XJ if needed
D = squareform(pdist(X,distfun))
```

Note that the non-absolute distances metric you want is **not symmetric**, but `pdist` only calculates one triangular half of the matrix and **`squareform` forces it to be symmetric**.  If that's not what you want, try a loop:

```
>> X = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
>> D = zeros(size(X,1),size(X,1));
>> % for i=1:size(X,1), D(:,i)=sum(bsxfun(@minus,X,X(i,:)),2); end % my guess
>> % but to get the desired result, here's the appropriate loop:
>> for i=1:size(X,1), D(:,i) = sum(bsxfun(@minus,X,X(:,i)),1); end
>> disp(D)
     0    -3    -6
     3     0    -3
     6     3     0
```

**EDIT**:  Solution for OP example data and desired matrix.

Comment: I really just want the city block metric minus the absolute values, but you supplied the answer to that as well, thanks!

Comment: Am I somehow entering it in wrong? I keep getting "distfunc" was previously used as a variable,
conflicting with its use here as the name of a function or
command."

Comment: Fixed `distfun` definition.  I was out to lunch earlier, sorry!  You need to use `bsxfun` for the minus operation you want, together with sum, and NO `abs` or `.^2`.  Tested this time around!